# ansi c udp server with select(). saving messages in linked list

Tags: c, сервер, select, list, udp

Пишу UDP server на Си, использовать функцию select() для множества клиентов. Сообщения сохранять в linked list. При распечатывании списка list должны быть все сохраненные ранее сообщения. Почему-то первое сообщение добавляется дважды, к тому же в список добавляется каждый раз новое сообщение, а старые пропадают и не печатаются.

Что делаю не так?

это server.c:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define MAXLEN 4096
char* toUpper(char*);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
slist_t *list = (slist_t*)malloc(sizeof(slist_t));
slist_init(list);
fd_set read_fds, write_fds;     // temp file descriptor list for select()
int sockfd;                             // socket descriptor
struct sockaddr_in srv, cli_addr;       // used by bind()
socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
int nbytes, portno; 
if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./server %s <port>\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}
portno = atoi(argv[1]);
if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0){
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
    exit(1);
}
else
    printf("Server : Socket() successful\n");
bzero(&srv, sizeof(srv));
/* create the socket */
srv.sin_family = AF_INET;
/* bind: socket ‘sockfd’ to port portno*/
srv.sin_port = htons(portno);
/* bind: a client may connect to any of my addresses */
srv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &srv, sizeof(srv)) < 0){
    perror("ERROR on binding");
    close(sockfd);
    exit(1);
}
else
    printf("Server : bind() successful\n");
//Now the UDP server is ready to accept packets…
printf("Server is ready to read\n");
    
while(1){
    char buf[MAXLEN];
    char copybuf[MAXLEN];
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &read_fds);
    int n = select(sockfd+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, 0, 0);
    if(n < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR Server : select()\n");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }   
    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &read_fds)) {
        printf("==========================\n");
        nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (nbytes < 0){
            perror("ERROR in recvfrom()");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Received packet from %s : %d\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));
        printf("Data: %s", buf);
    }
    FD_CLR(sockfd, &read_fds);
    memcpy(copybuf, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(list == NULL){
        perror("List is empty. Server is not ready to write.");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &write_fds);
    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &write_fds)){
        nbytes = sendto(sockfd, copybuf, MAXLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &srv, sizeof(srv));
        if(nbytes < 0) {
            perror("ERROR in sendto");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
        toUpper(copybuf);
        printf("Server is ready to write\n");
        printf("Send to client: %s", copybuf);
        printf("==========================");
        memset(copybuf, 0, sizeof(copybuf));
        FD_CLR(sockfd, &write_fds);
    }
    slist_append(list, buf);
    printlist(list);
    printf("%d\n", slist_size(list));
    char ch;
    ch = getchar();
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
}
close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
char* toUpper(char* str){
if(str != NULL){    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if( str[i] <= 'z' && str[i] >= 'a')
        {
            str[i] += 'A' - 'a';
        }
    }
    return str;
}
return NULL;
}
```

а это list - функции init(), append() и print()

```
void printlist(slist_t *list){
  slist_node_t* l = list->head;
  printf("\n");
  printf("List is: ");
  while(l != NULL) {
    printf("%s ", (char*) l->data);
    l = l->next;
  }
}
int slist_append(slist_t *list, void *data)
{
   if(list == NULL) {
      printf("ERROR: the list wasn't initialized\n");
    return -1;
    }
    slist_node_t* newNode = malloc(sizeof(slist_node_t));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(list->head == NULL){
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
       list->tail->next = newNode;
       list->tail = newNode;
    }
    list->size++;
    return 0;
}
void slist_init(slist_t *list){
   list->head = NULL;
   list->tail = NULL;
   list->size = 0;
}
```

Вот что получается пока что:
[image: 1]

Comment: Не понятно, зачем вот это `FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &write_fds);
    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &write_fds)){ ...` нужно? А списки оттестируйте в какой-нибудь тестовой программке, читающей строки в консоли.

Comment: список тестирован. сам по себе работает как надо.

Comment: Наверное с нулями в конце строк проблема. Смотрите `nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, ...` ... `memcpy(copybuf, buf, sizeof(buf));` а между ними чего-то вроде `buf[nbytes] = 0;` я не вижу, а ведь recvfrom нолик после прочитанных данных не пишет.

Answer (score 1):

Решила. Вот код:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "slist.c"
#define MAXLEN 4096

char* toUpper(char*);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    slist_t *list = (slist_t*)malloc(sizeof(slist_t));
    slist_init(list);
    fd_set read_fds, write_fds;             // temp file descriptor list for select()
    int sockfd;                             // socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_in srv, cli_addr;       // used by bind()
socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
int nbytes, portno; 
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 0; 
//check command line arguments 
if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./server %s <port>\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}
portno = atoi(argv[1]);
if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0){
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
    exit(1);
}
else
    printf("Server : Socket() successful\n");
//bzero(&srv, sizeof(srv));

/* bind: use the Internet address family */

/* create the socket */
srv.sin_family = AF_INET;
/* bind: socket ‘sockfd’ to port portno*/
srv.sin_port = htons(portno);
/* bind: a client may connect to any of my addresses */
srv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &srv, sizeof(srv)) < 0){
    perror("ERROR on binding");
    close(sockfd);
    exit(1);
}
else
    printf("Server : bind() successful\n");
//Now the UDP server is ready to accept packets…
while(1){           
    fflush(stdout);
    char* buf = (char*)malloc(MAXLEN);                      // message buf
    char* copybuf = (char*)malloc(MAXLEN);
    memset(buf, 0, strlen(buf));
    bzero(buf, MAXLEN);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &read_fds);
    int n = select(sockfd+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, 0, 0);
    if(n < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR Server : select()\n");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &read_fds)) {
        printf("Server is ready to read\n");
        nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (nbytes < 0){
            perror("ERROR in recvfrom()");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
    //  printf("Received packet from %s : %d\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));
    //  printf("Data: %s", buf);
        FD_CLR(sockfd, &read_fds);
    }
    if(strlen(buf) != 0){
        slist_append(list, buf);
        //printlist(list);              //you may see the list
        memcpy(copybuf, buf, strlen(buf));
        if(list == NULL){
            perror("List is empty. Server is not ready to write.");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
        else{
            FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
            FD_SET(sockfd, &write_fds);
            if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &write_fds)){
                toUpper(copybuf);
                nbytes = sendto(sockfd, copybuf, MAXLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));
                if(nbytes < 0) {
                    perror("ERROR in sendto");
                    close(sockfd);
                    exit(1);
                }
                printf("Server is ready to write\n");
                //printf("Send to client: %s", copybuf);
                //printf("==========================\n");
                printf("\n");
                memset(&copybuf, 0, sizeof(copybuf));
                FD_CLR(sockfd, &write_fds);
            }
        }
    }
    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
}
close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: полностью работает

Comment: И что Вы хотите? Чтобы Вам указали на ошибки?